# Partial match of strings for filter method in Google Sheet GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, match, partial

I have the following codes:

```js
var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val){
    return val[C2] == "ANTHONY";
    });
```

This code works fine for an exact match. But if I would like to look for any values that ends with Y, this does not return anything:

```js
  var filteredRange = rangeVals.filter(function(val){
    return val[C2] == "*Y";
    });
```

I have tried to us wildcard "%Y" but apparently this is not the correct way either. 
I have tried to look into this resource of RegExp from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) but I can't seem to integrate the information for this purpose. I have read a lot of different posts here but none seem to address what I need so far. Can someone point me in the right direction? I am interested in knowing how to retrieve values that match based on a partial match, e.g. beginning with a letter, or ending with a letter, or containing string like 'cde' in 'abcdefg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the element, which has `Y` at the last character, from the 2 dimensional array using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
return val[C2] == "*Y";
```

To:

```
return val[C2].slice(-1) == "Y";
```

or

```
return val[C2][val[C2].length - 1] == "Y";
```

or

```
return /Y$/.test(val[C2]); // regex is used.
```

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the element which has `abc` at the last character, please modify `return val[C2] == "*Y";` to `return /abc$/.test(val[C2]);` and `return val[C2].slice(-3) === "abc";`.
- When you want to retrieve the element which includes `cde` in the value,. please modify `return val[C2] == "*Y";` to `return val[C2].indexOf("cde") > -1;`.

#### References:

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: " return /Y$/.test(val[C2]); " worked great. The slice method and the [[C2].length - 1] returned error. Do you have any idea why? text type? Would you like me to post a sample of my data?

Comment: @Thien Pham Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Although I'm not sure about your goal, if you want to use other patterns except for the regex `return /Y$/.test(val[C2]);`, please provide the detail information about `error` of `returned error` and the sample values.